# looping folder names to variable using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, directory, var

My weekness is loops, however I need one for todays purpose. Dose anyone know how I can loop all folder names within a parent directory to a variable?

I need to do this using vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Dim folders As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\your\starting\directory\")
   For Each folder As String In folders
        'do something
   Next
```